# Lambda is not able to access API gateway Invoke URL

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, cors, aws-api-gateway

I have written an AWS Lambda function in AWS account A and exposed one api in AWS account B. The api url looks like `https://*******.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com:443/abc`.

Now, when I try to access this url through Lambda in AWS account A, I am getting `forbidden` exception. Also, I am able to access `https://google.com` from Lambda. The API exposed in AWS account B is working through Postman. Please suggest if I am missing something.

**Also, Forbidden is not coming from the api if I hit the api from postman with wrong authorization token or no auth token.**

```
{
    "statusCode": 403,
    "body": "{\"message\":\"Forbidden\"}",
    "headers": {
        "server": "Server",
        "date": "Thu, 10 Nov 2022 07:03:35 GMT",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "content-length": "23",
        "x-amzn-requestid": "**************",
        "x-amzn-errortype": "ForbiddenException",
        "x-amz-apigw-id": "**************",
        "connection": "close"
    },
    "request": {
        "uri": {
            "protocol": "https:",
            "slashes": true,
            "auth": null,
            "host": "*******.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com",
            "port": 443,
            "hostname": "*******.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com",
            "hash": null,
            "search": null,
            "query": null,
            "pathname": "*****/verify-token",
            "path": "*****/verify-token",
            "href": "https:******.execute-api.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/*****/verify-token"
        },
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "Authorization": "correctToken",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
            "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 12_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/69.0.3497.105 Mobile/15E148 Safari/605.1"
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
This is the issue:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-vpc-connections/

```
NodeJs Code
const request = require("request");
 request(authRequestBody, (error, response) => {
Business Logic    
--------------------------------------------
    });
```

Comment: Forbidden means you are invoking your api incorrectly. You haven't provided any information about the api and how you are using it, thus it's not possible to provide precise answer.

Comment: Do you have authorization on the api?

Comment: Yes, I am passing authorization in headers

Comment: Need more information as other posters have suggested.  Ie Is the lambda attached to a VPC?

Comment: @RichS3, yes lambda is attached to a VPC

Comment: @Marcin, I have provided enough information now, can you pls help me resolve it